# Ergotron Neo-Flex in hand luggage?

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

I am travelling with AirBaltic and without the checked baggage, only with hand baggage. I would like to get this in my hand luggage:

[image]

It is small enough but it is metal so I am reconsidering if it is possible to have it in hand luggage.

Can you have ergotron neo-flex in hand luggage?

Comment: The majority of airport security checks that I have been through in the last 15 years would not have let me take that in carry-on luggage, regardless of what website documentation may say. YMMV. But, YMMnV.

Comment: In case you are wondering, too, it is a support for a computer monitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other than the obvious (knives and blades), any metal item with sharp edges that can cause harm to people is a good candidate for refusal in hand luggage. This is an international regulation coming from ICAO and [IATA](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/ops-infra/baggage/Pages/check-bag.aspx) and other authorities/regulators.

**What to do?**
If you have checked luggage allowance, use it. Check your hand luggage, if it's small then wrap it with plastic at the airport to add more protection.

Other option would be taking the risk if the device is cheap enough, explain to the security officer and pray they'll accept it. Unless you know someone in the flight who is checking-in a luggage then ask him/her to take it.

Answer (score 2):

Oh it's not just me who is hauling a VESA mountable giant monitor? I will readily presume that's why you want to carry a VESA mount.

So if the question is, I have a 20" carry on monitor in my backpack, it's VESA mountable, what do I mount it on, I can help!

I can recommend two options: some graphics tablet monitors have VESA stands and at least the stand for the YiyNova tablets is [available](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005OGV54K). This is pretty OK. Not great because I wouldn't really dare to use it at 90 degrees but close enough.

Another option is to use a [K&M 19685](http://products.k-m.de/us/product?info=1214&x97c6d=e32ee21241cbf04dda73762d7e5a5401) VESA mount together with a tripod. I found that the relevant [K&M tripod](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/838748-REG/K_M_23150_500_55_23150_Tabletop_Microphone_Stand.html) is not stable enough the legs are too close for a 18" x 10" -- it falls along a diagonal. I have not yet bought a replacement because I am testing the YiyNova stand from above but I am eyeing the BEXIN M225S (also EOSCN ES-6 and probably a bazillion other names) because it's very small, the [legs open very far](https://www.flickr.com/photos/slmka/15511629102) and it claims to hold up to 8.8lbs and the ball head is removable which is quite good because it's the ball head is just wobbling problem for this purpose.